# Special characters with JBoss CLI

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, special-characters

I am in domain mode with JBoss 6.4.8 version.
I want to add these 4 system properties by CLI :

```
1- /host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})

2- /host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})
```

It doesn't work

```
 "outcome" => "failed",
    "result" => undefined,
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010839: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers.",
    "rolled-back" => true
```

As you can see there is `$`, : and `{}` characters, is it my problem ?

In the past, i encountered this problem with the `$` and i solve it by `\$` but here it doesn't work !

Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Ludo

Answer (score 3):

Notice, vault references are not resolved if vault configuration was recently added, a restart or reload of the configuration is required before you set a vault reference.

### When not resolving parameter values

When JBoss-cli is NOT configured to resolve parameter values (`resolve-parameter-values` set to `false` in `jboss-cli.xml` -by default-):

a) Escape with `\$` when using the `--command` cli parameter (aka non-interactive mode)

```
/path/to/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="/host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=\${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})"
```

b) Use direct reference when using interactive mode

```
/host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})
```

### When resolving parameter values

When JBoss-cli is configured to resolve parameter values (`resolve-parameter-values` set to `true` in `jboss-cli.xml`):

c) Escape with `\$\$` when using the `--command` cli parameter (this prevents parameter expansion in bash )

```
/path/to/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="/host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=\$\${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})"
```

d) Escape with `$$` when using the `--file` cli parameter

```
/path/to/jboss-cli.sh -c --file="/path/to/commands.cli"
```

`commands.cli` contents:

```
/host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=$${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})"
```

or interactive mode

```
/host=myserver/server-config=node/system-property=javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword:add(boot-time=false,value=$${VAULT::vault_block::attribute_name::1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about 6.4, but in 7 as per https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/single/management-cli-guide/#cli_special_characters you can enclose a value with `""` or `{}`, so in your case you should put it inside `""`

Comment: hi,
ok thanks a lot for your help
i will test it !
but actually our project is out of date !

thx a lot

ludo