# Using literal variables in a Wildfly OFFLINE CLI

Tags: variables, escaping, command-line-interface, wildfly, offline-mode

I'd like to use an offline Wildfly CLI to add system properties

The problem is that the value should be a variable

This is the desired result:

```
        <property name="user.country" value="${country}"/>
```

the problem is that the CLI try to resolve the variable

```
[disconnected /] embed-server
[standalone@embedded /] /system-property=user.country:add(value="${country}")
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${country}'",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I tried to escape the '$' with '$$' or '\$', but it doesn't worked.

Or rather, with '$$' I got

```
<property name="user.language" value="$${countrylowercase}"/>
```

If I run the server an retry with a connect CLI , it works normally.

How to do this offline?

As a workaround I'm doing a sed on the standalone to replace '$${' with '${', but it's not very clean...

Comment: based on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612127/special-characters-with-jboss-cli) it depends on the configuration of your `jboss-cli.sh` (`jboss-cli.xml` and the `resolve-parameter-values` property). But I've tried it for myself and it doesn't work either at it always tries to resolve the expression ... Maybe you can raise an issue in the WildFly forum (https://wildfly.org/gethelp/)?

Comment: Hi @rieckpil  . Yes, the `resolve-parameter-values` is false by default so the CLI should not try to resolve, and put the direct reference. I'll try to ask in the WF forum, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a property file written like this:

```
cat cli.property

    country=$country
    countrylowercase=$countrylowercase
```

```
cat cli.commands

    embed-server 
    /system-property=user.language:add(value="${countrylowercase}") 
    /system-property=user.region:add(value="${country}") 
    /system-property=user.country:add(value="${country}") 
    stop-embedded-server
```

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --properties=./cli.property --file=./cli.commands

{"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

It's important to respect the syntax, because the following forma will also fail by using embedded mode

```
cat cli.property

    country=${country}
    countrylowercase=${countrylowercase}
```